# iOS 7 Custom Button broken action/outlet

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uibutton, segue

So I'm trying to create a custom button class with a border around it and the border and text color changes to 1/2 alpha and back once pressed. For more or less I have this working, but for some reason it's stopping my button from pushing to another view. I'm not sure why. Can someone explain to me how this would break the action?

Here is my code for my custom button class:

```
- (void)initialize{
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.f;
    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}

- (instancetype)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    // When the button is pressed the border color chage to 1/2 alpha
    UIColor *transBlack = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5f];
    [self.layer setBorderColor: transBlack.CGColor];
    //EDIT based on solution
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    // When the button is pressed the border color changes back to black
    [self.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor ].CGColor];
    //EDIT based on solution
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

I have the buttons in my Storyboard all in one view. They each should push to a new view, different from the rest. I have the segue in Storyboard. But when I add the code to change the border color, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Have you tried calling [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]; and [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event]; within those two methods in addition to your custom border code?

Comment: I just tired it and it seems to solve the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to pass the touch events to the base class after you do your color-setting work, e.g.:

`[super touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];`

and

`[super touchesEnded: touches withEvent: event];`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling `super` in your overridden touchesBegan / touchesEnded?

Per the docs:

> The default implementation of this method does nothing. However immediate UIKit subclasses of UIResponder, particularly UIView, forward the message up the responder chain.

Seeing as UIButton is a subclass of of UIView, then you probably should be calling these.